# Why isn't Idris able to typecheck the following code?

Tags: idris

I'm trying to see how "smart" the unification is in Idris. Type-checking fails in the following simple case:

```
GetBoolOrNat : Bool -> Type
GetBoolOrNat False  = Bool
GetBoolOrNat True   = Nat

Func : (b : Bool) -> (GetBoolOrNat b)
Func False  = False
Func _      = Z
```

The error is:

```
   |
75 | Func _     = Z
   |                   ^
When checking right hand side of Func with expected type
        GetBoolOrNat b

Type mismatch between
        Nat (Type of 0)
and
        GetBoolOrNat b (Expected type)
```

For a human it is obvious that in the last case, 'b' is 'True' and the function type is 'Bool -> Nat'. It works fine if you replace '_' with 'True'.

Can someone please explain why it doesn't work? Is this limitation related to the fact that full higher order unification is undecidable? I don't know much about higher order unification (I think Idris uses "Miller Unification").

Comment: I only add this as a comment since I am not sure if this is true, but idris does not look at previous cases when working on the current one.